# generics with interfaces and validators

Tags: java

I have:

```
Generic interface with method isValid (T obj).    
Driver class with parameters such as age, experience, license etc.  VaLidator for   
Driver Class which checks if Driver is Valid.
```

So I need a  validator for the Driver class.

```
public class Driver <T>{
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private String secondname;
    private int dateofbirth;
    private T pass;
    private T dateofissue;

    public int getDateofbirth() {
        return dateofbirth;
    }

    public T getPass() {
        return pass;
    }

    public T getDateofissue() {
        return dateofissue;
    }



}
```

```
public interface Validator <T> {
    boolean isValid (T obj);
}
```

```
class DriverValidator<T> implements Validator {
```

I do not know how I should do it. For any explanation will be very grateful

Comment: How could we help with the validation when we don't know what rules consider a driver to be valid? Also, `class DriverValidator<T> implements Validator` should probably be `class DriverValidator implements Validator<Driver>`. Also sounds as if `Driver` would not have a type parameter (you currently declare it with a type parameter).

Comment: How could we help with the validation when we don't know what rules consider a driver to be valid? -it can be any rules you will, like if the age >35 and experience >3.

Comment: A different approach - read this blog post: [Defensive Programming via Validating Decorators](https://www.yegor256.com/2016/01/26/defensive-programming.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in comments above it's not easy to help in this case, because the kind of validation is not known, also it's a little bit odd when seeing generic type  is used 2 times by different getters. Also the dateOfBirth variable should be a long, a Date or a LocalDate.

But anyway, here is an example of an implementation of a validator to explain the technical concept (of course you have to add more checks, but the idea should be clear) :

```java
public class DriverValidator<T> implements Validator<Driver<T>> {

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(Driver<T> driver) {
        if (driver==null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (driver.getPass() == null) {
            /* e.g. when this field may not be null...*/
            return false;
        }
        // ... do more checks - e.g. check old enough etc.
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: that's what i need for understanding ) Thanks